# Crystal Reports with Parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an MVC application and I am using CrystalReportViewer 12 to display a crystal report. The way I do it is the user clicks on the preview link and a pop-up window comes up with the report in it. I've been through my set of issues and making MVC work well with images,etc. but now the reports work well. The last hurdle I have is reports with parameters. 
If a report has parameters I am supposed to see a prompt which prompts for the parameter data. HOwever I don't see that prompt come up and instead I see a message on the page saying "Missing parameter Values".  Is there any special setting that I need to have to turn ON the parameter prompt? Thanks in advance.

Susan

Answer (score 3):

```
CrystalReportsViewer.EnableParameterPrompt = True
```